# How to use API Monitor to filter function parameters?

Tags: debugging, process, api

I am monitoring a process using API monitor. I'm getting a lot of API calls unrelated to what I am interested in monitoring. I know about the Display Filter and have been using to filter API Names to what I am interested in but I am still getting a lot function calls with parameters that I am not interested in.

Is there way to filter out/in function calls with certain parameters?

Comment: Name the program and the function you're interested in.

Comment: *which* API monitor? Does the documentation mention anything?

Comment: @IgorSkochinksy the name of the tool is API Monitor [link](http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor)